# How can I create a TikZ shape that is a hyperlink to specific overlay of a slide in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, hyperref

I'm a TikZ newbie trying to create hyperlinked TikZ shapes. I use MiKTeX 2.9 and xelatex. See the MWE below.

Issues:

- The four boxes are created by a set of nodes in a matrix. For some reason, Box 1 is not hyperlinked to Slide 2. Is it because it is in a matrix?
- The arrow on slide 2 is hyperlinked to slide 1. But what if I want it to hyperlink to overlay #2 on slide 1. If just replace `hyperlink node=slide1` with `hyperlink node=slide1<2>`, the hyperlink goes dead.

Thanks for any advice/explanation/help.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,125,195}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{191,215,48}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows,backgrounds,intersections,shapes,decorations,calc,positioning,graphs]


% Hyperlinking nodes
\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{0pt}
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
            \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
            \n1={\x2-\x1},
            \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0, outer sep=0, anchor=north west,at=(\p1)]
            {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}
        }
    },
}

% TiKZ visible on

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\hypertarget{slide1}{} Slide 1}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas ={scale=0.75,yshift=-25mm},
            hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
            vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
            param/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm,
                very thick,
                draw = mygreen,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = mygreen!50!white!50,
                align = center},
            important/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm,
                very thick,
                draw = red!50!black!50,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = red!50!black!20,
                font = \LARGE,
                align = center},
            values/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm,
                very thick,
                draw = yellow!50!red!50,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = yellow!50!red!20,
                align = center},
            ivalues/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm,
                very thick,
                draw = yellow!50!red!50,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = yellow!50!red!20,
                font = \LARGE,
                align = center},
            >=stealth',thick,myblue,text=black,
            every new ->/.style={shorten >=1pt}
            ]
            \matrix[row sep=20mm, column sep=25mm, align=center]
            {
                \node (B4) [visible on=<8->, param, minimum size=2cm] {Box 4};&

                \node (c1) [visible on=<1->] {}; &

                \node [hyperlink node=slide2, visible on=<2->, param, minimum
                size=2cm] (B1) {Box1}; \\

                \node (B3) [visible on=<6->,param, minimum size=2cm] {Box 3};&
                \node (c2) {}; &
                \node (B2) [visible on=<4->,param, minimum size=2cm] {Box 2};\\
            };

            \graph{
                (c1) -> [visible on=<1->, align = center] (B1);
                (B1) -> [visible on=<3->, align = center] (B2);
                (B2) -> [visible on=<5->, align = center] (B3);
                (B3) -> [visible on=<7->, align = center] (B4);
                (B4) -> [visible on=<9->, align = center] (c1);
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\hypertarget{Slide2}{} Slide 2}
    \begin{block}{BLAH BLAH}
        Foobar
    \end{block}

    \begin{textblock*}{1cm}(4cm,4cm)
        TEST
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[hyperlink node=slide1, visible on=<2->, single arrow,draw=mygreen,fill=mygreen!50!white!50,minimum
            height=1cm,shape border rotate=90] at (0,0) {Up};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem has something to do with all the \begin{tikzpicture[] parameters.  If you remove them (and correct the spelling of Slide2) it works.  As for reaching a specific page, you can use \hypertarget{slide\thepage}{} and reference \hyperlink{slide2}{...} to reach page 2.

Comment: Actually, there should already be a {page.\the\Hy@pagecounter} anchor.

Comment: The[ transform canvas] option seems to be the culprit.  [scale=.75] by itself is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by my comments above:

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,125,195}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{191,215,48}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows,backgrounds,intersections,shapes,decorations,calc,positioning,graphs]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\theslide}{\the\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

% Hyperlinking nodes
\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{0pt}
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
            \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
            \n1={\x2-\x1},
            \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0, outer sep=0, anchor=north west,at=(\p1)]
            {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}
        }
    },
}

% TiKZ visible on

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\hypertarget{slide1<\theslide>}{}Slide 1}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,
            hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
            vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
            param/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm,
                very thick,
                draw = mygreen,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = mygreen!50!white!50,
                align = center},
            important/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm,
                very thick,
                draw = red!50!black!50,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = red!50!black!20,
                font = \LARGE,
                align = center},
            values/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm,
                very thick,
                draw = yellow!50!red!50,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = yellow!50!red!20,
                align = center},
            ivalues/.style={
                rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm,
                very thick,
                draw = yellow!50!red!50,
                top color = white,
                bottom color = yellow!50!red!20,
                font = \LARGE,
                align = center},
            >=stealth',thick,myblue,text=black,
            every new ->/.style={shorten >=1pt}
            ]

            \matrix[row sep=20mm, column sep=25mm, align=center]
            {
                \node (B4) [visible on=<8->, param, minimum size=2cm] {Box 4};&

                \node (c1) [visible on=<1->] {}; &

                \node [hyperlink node=Slide2, visible on=<2->, param, minimum
                size=2cm] (B1) {Box1}; \\

                \node (B3) [visible on=<6->,param, minimum size=2cm] {Box 3};&
                \node (c2) {}; &
                \node (B2) [visible on=<4->,param, minimum size=2cm] {Box 2};\\
            };

            \graph{
                (c1) -> [visible on=<1->, align = center] (B1);
                (B1) -> [visible on=<3->, align = center] (B2);
                (B2) -> [visible on=<5->, align = center] (B3);
                (B3) -> [visible on=<7->, align = center] (B4);
                (B4) -> [visible on=<9->, align = center] (c1);
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\hypertarget{Slide2}{}Slide 2}
    \begin{block}{BLAH BLAH}

    \end{block}

    \begin{textblock*}{1cm}(4cm,4cm)
        TEST
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[hyperlink node=slide1<2>,visible on=<2->, 
            single arrow,draw=mygreen,fill=mygreen!50!white!50,minimum
            height=1cm,shape border rotate=90] at (0,0) {Up};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't understand the `hyperlink node=page.2` syntax.

Comment: Every slide is automatically assigned a hypertarget of the form {page.1} {page.2} and so on.  (I'm not sure if this is documented.  I got it from the source code.)  Note, this is usually but not necessarily {page.\thepage}.  Hyperref uses its own page counter to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Aha. But the problem is that I don't know beforehand what the page number would be.....

Comment: I created \theslide macro which should correspond to beamer's slide <> specification.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. I also removed the transform canvas and just  used a `\resizebox` (after doing the `replacement ampersand` trick for the matrix...